# Is it possible to add hook function when minimize an UWP app

Tags: uwp

In my design, when an UWP app of full screen mode launches a thrid party app using below code, itself will be minimized by system.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("yourprotocolhere://"));
```

How could I avoid it?
My purpose is to launch the 3rd party app while keep my UWP app still full screen occupied. And my idea is to add hook function to the minimized event.

But how to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launcher provides `LaunchOptions` for launch configuration, You can use `LaunchOptions.DesiredRemainingView` to specify the desired size of the target window.

```cs
var options = new LauncherOptions();
options.DesiredRemainingView = ViewSizePreference.UseNone;
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("yourprotocolhere://"), options);
```

But according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcheroptions.desiredremainingview?view=winrt-19041#Windows_System_LauncherOptions_DesiredRemainingView):

> Windows takes into account multiple different factors when determining the source app's final window size, for example, the preference of the source app, the number of apps on screen, the screen orientation, and so on. By setting DesiredRemainingView, you aren't guaranteed a specific windowing behavior for the source app.

This means that the final presentation state of the target application is determined by the system. When your application is in full screen, awakening the application at this time will cause the current application to exit the full screen state and minimize it. This is due to the current window management settings in Windows, and UWP apps cannot change this behavior.